# I am getting NullPointerException in my Spring MVC project?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a simple Library project based on spring MVC framework. I am going to add a new author to my author table but I am getting NullPointerException. 
I provided add classes related to this function below. can anybody say what is wrong?

```
@Controller
public class AuthorController {

@RequestMapping("/addAuthor")
protected ModelAndView addAuthor() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("addAuthor");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping("/addAuthorExecution")
protected ModelAndView addAuthorExecution(
        @RequestParam("authorName") String authorName) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext cnx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    AuthorService authorService = (AuthorService) cnx.getBean("authorService");
    authorService.addAuthor(authorName);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("adminFunctionsPage");
    model.addObject("successMsg", "Your request has been processed Successfully.");
    return model;
}
}
```

Service Class:

```
public class AuthorService {
@Autowired
Author author;
@Autowired
AuthorDAO authorDAO;

public void addAuthor(String authorName) throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    AuthorDAO authorDAO = new AuthorDAO();
    authorDAO.addAuthor(authorName);
}
}
```

DAO class:

```
public class AuthorDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport {

public void addAuthor(String authorName) {
    String sql = "insert into tbl_author (authorName) values (?)";
    this.getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, new Object[] { authorName });
}


private static final class AuthorMapper implements RowMapper<Author> {
    @Autowired
    Author author;

    @Override
    public Author mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        author.setAuthorId(rs.getInt("authorId"));
        author.setAuthorName(rs.getString("authorName"));
        return author;
    }

}
}
```

Model Class:

```
public class Author {
int authorId;
String authorName;

public int getAuthorId() {
    return authorId;
}

public void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
    this.authorId = authorId;
}

public String getAuthorName() {
    return authorName;
}

public void setAuthorName(String authorName) {
    this.authorName = authorName;
}

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.DAO" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.Service" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/library"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
</bean>

<bean id="author" class="com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.model.Author"/>


<bean id="authorDAO" class="com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.DAO.AuthorDAO" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="authorService" class="com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.service.AuthorService"/>
```

Error:

```
    'INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Feb 24, 2015 1:16:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/LibrarySpringMVCProject] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.DAO.AuthorDAO.addAuthor(AuthorDAO.java:32)
    at com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.service.AuthorService.addAuthor(AuthorService.java:40)
    at com.hojat.LibSpringMVCProject.controller.AuthorController.addAuthorExecution(AuthorController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)'
```

Comment: The error is at line 32 of AuthorDAO. What is this line? What do you deduce? Don't you think the row mapper should create a new Author for each row, instead of modifying the same (not) autowired author every time it's called? On the other hand, why construct an AuthorDAO since you already have one, autowired by Spring in the service?

Comment: It is done. The problem was the additional AuthorDAO in my Service class. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hello could you try

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library"/>
```

instead of

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/library"/>
```

It will be problem.

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes

1. You are autowiring the POJO entity class `Auther`. This is wrong.
2. Hope you have `@Service` annotation on the `AuthorService`
3. You are creating an object of the the `AuthorDAO` inside the `addAuthor` method. You should note the `AutherDAO` should not be manually constructed as there are `autowired` object available inside that class `AutherDAO.AuthorMapper`. By manually constructing them these auto wiring will not get wired to objects.

If I completely rewrite your service class, it would be something like this.

```
    @Service
    public class AuthorService {

        @Autowired
        AuthorDAO authorDAO;

        public void addAuthor(String authorName) throws Exception {
           authorDAO.addAuthor(authorName);
        }
    }
```